# Math : How many combinations are there with m people and n gifts？

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

I met a math question. Let's say there are `m` people and `n` gifts. A people may receive all `n` gifts or `a` (0 <= `a` < `n`) gifts or nothing (0 gift). But all the gifts need to gave away. In addition, all the gifts are different. So, my question is how many possible ways to send gifts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because math questions should be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/, not here. Please delete this.

Answer (score 2):

The first gift can be given to anyone of m persons. Also the second gift can be given to anyone of m persons. The same for the third, forth, fifth, ... gift.

There are therefore m^n possible ways to hand out the gifts.

Comment: What if all the gifts are different?

Comment: @张俊旭. Do you mean if all gifts should be given to different persons?